# Running rspec from within ruby multiple times within the same process

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

I am creating a test automation tool that runs a rspec test from within ruby, not from command line.

I run my test like this that runs and gives me a output hash with pass / fail etc.

```
config = RSpec.configuration

json_formatter = RSpec::Core::Formatters::JsonFormatter.new(config.out)
reporter =  RSpec::Core::Reporter.new(json_formatter)
config.instance_variable_set(:@reporter, reporter)

RSpec::Core::Runner.run(["#{Rails.root}/spec/test1_spec.rb"])

puts json_formatter.output_hash
```

All is great until i run it again and i get the error

```
> undefined method `visit' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_7:0x007ff3d343d978>
```

how do i reload / make sure all spec_helper and files are loaded before i run it again ?

thanks
Rick

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
require 'spec_helper'
```

to the top of each spec file.

Comment: test has this and runs fine from bundle exec rspec from command line and also runs fine running above code from rails console.    BUT it does not run a second time as gets the above error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems, turns out it can be fixed with one line of code only:

```
require 'capybara'
include Capybara::DSL # Add this line right after requiring capybara
```

Source: http://codedecoder.wordpress.com/2013/01/10/undefined-method-visit-for-rspec-capybara/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and had to do a `RSpec#reset` between runs to make sure everything was cleaned up.

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-core/RSpec#reset-class_method